# arrow between columns in tabularx using tikzmark

Tags: tabularx, tikz-arrows

I want to have a table with three columns and to have some arrows between the row in the table. So this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tm}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture,
   baseline=(#1.base), anchor=west] \node [inner sep=0pt] (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c|c|c }
    \ul{livedb} & \ul{app code} & \ul{intowodw fact.podio\_orders only} \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \ul{property table} & & \\
    id \tm{A} & \tm{1} property.id or id & \\
    country\_id \tm{B} & \tm{2} property.country\_id & \\
    name \tm{C} & \tm{3} property.name & \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Caption}\label{tab:danos}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
   \draw[<->] (A) edge (1)
              (B) edge (2)
              (C) edge (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But this is what I am having, and I would like to have the arrows aligned to the text but I am having trouble to.

[image]

Do you know how to do it? and can you help me on this?

Best

Comment: it is much easier to answer if you provide a real test document that produces the image shown  with `\documentclass` and without `...` that people need to fill in.

Comment: What do you mean by "aligned to the text"? Do you want to push the arrows a bit higher than the baseline?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

With help of `tikznode` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}       % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c|c|c }
livedb      & app code  & intowodw fact.podio\_orders only    \\
    \hline
property table          &                                       &   \\
\tikzmarknode{a1}{id}   & \tikzmarknode{a2}{property.id or id}  &   \\
\tikzmarknode{b1}{country\_id}   & \tikzmarknode{b2}{property.country\_id}    & \\
\tikzmarknode{c1}{name} & \tikzmarknode{c2}{property.name}      &   \\
\end{tabularx}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
                    every edge/.append style={<->, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt}]
\draw   (a1) edge (a2)
        (b1) edge (b2)
        (c1) edge (c2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: for proper result you need two compilation. Probably you will need to force the first compilation due to bug in the (recent on CTAN) `tikznode` library or you can try to find its version available on "github", where is fix for it.

Comment: Nice thank you!

Comment: @BarthelemyLancelot, do my answer solve your problem? if it solve, please up-vote it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: yes it did and I would have been pleased to upvote you but I can't : I don't have enough reputations ahahah

Comment: @BarthelemyLancelot, i know that, but you can accept them ...